# Casting comma separated string to integer to be used in "IN" SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I pass a comma separated numbers as string to a stored procedure, the parameters are used in `IN` keyword, however when I execute the SP (with parameters like "1,2") it gives me an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type
>   int.

The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Reports].[LocationSummary]
    @dtFrom VARCHAR(MAX),
    @dtTo VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passTypeId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passCategoryId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passTransId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @printOption VARCHAR(MAX),
    @printLocationId VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Admins.PLocations.ArabicName AS PLocationA, 
           Admins.PLocations.EnglishName AS PLocationE,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.Info.Printed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Printed,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.Info.Printed = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NotPrinted,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.PortPrintLog.PortId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Reprinted

    FROM Port.Info INNER JOIN
           Port.PortRequests ON 
           Port.Info.PassRequestId = Port.PortRequests.ID LEFT JOIN
           Port.PortDefinitions ON 
           Port.PortRequests.PassDefinitionID = Port.PortDefinitions.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortCategories ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassCategoryId = Admins.PortCategories.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortTypes ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassTypeId = Admins.PortTypes.ID  INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortTransactionTypes ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassTransactionTypeId = Admins.PortTransactionTypes.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PLocations ON 
           Port.Info.PrintLocationID = Admins.PLocations.ID LEFT JOIN
           Port.PortPrintLog ON Port.PortPrintLog.PortId = Port.Info.ID

    WHERE 
         (@dtFrom IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.IssuanceDate IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.IssuanceDate >= @dtFrom)
         AND (@dtTo IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.ExpiryDate IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.ExpiryDate <= @dtTo)
         AND ((Admins.PortTypes.ID IN (CAST(@passTypeId AS INT)))
         AND (Admins.PortCategories.ID IN (CAST(@passCategoryId)))
         AND (Admins.PortTransactionTypes.ID IN (CAST(@passTransId)))
         AND (Port.Info.PrintLocationID IN (CAST(@PrintLocationId AS INT))))

    GROUP BY Admins.PrintLocations.ArabicName, Admins.PrintLocations.EnglishName
```

How can I avoid that error? should I use a function to `Split` the string? Can I see some example for that function?

Answer (score 5):

@jyparask has given dynamic query , you can use that otherwise try to implement following logic. you have more then one column otherwise i have done the changes.

```
Declare @var1 as varchar(2000)
Declare @var2 as varchar(2000)
Set @var1 = '31,39,41,45'
Set @var2 = ',' + @var1 + ','
select * from Table1 Where Charindex(','+cast(Col1 as varchar)+',', @var2) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a dynamic sql:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Reports].[LocationSummary]
    @dtFrom VARCHAR(MAX),
    @dtTo VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passTypeId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passCategoryId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passTransId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @printOption VARCHAR(MAX),
    @printLocationId VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 
    'SELECT Admins.PLocations.ArabicName AS PLocationA, 
           Admins.PLocations.EnglishName AS PLocationE,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.Info.Printed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Printed,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.Info.Printed = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NotPrinted,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.PortPrintLog.PortId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Reprinted

    FROM Port.Info INNER JOIN
           Port.PortRequests ON 
           Port.Info.PassRequestId = Port.PortRequests.ID LEFT JOIN
           Port.PortDefinitions ON 
           Port.PortRequests.PassDefinitionID = Port.PortDefinitions.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortCategories ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassCategoryId = Admins.PortCategories.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortTypes ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassTypeId = Admins.PortTypes.ID  INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortTransactionTypes ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassTransactionTypeId = Admins.PortTransactionTypes.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PLocations ON 
           Port.Info.PrintLocationID = Admins.PLocations.ID LEFT JOIN
           Port.PortPrintLog ON Port.PortPrintLog.PortId = Port.Info.ID

    WHERE 
         (@dtFrom IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.IssuanceDate IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.IssuanceDate >= @dtFrom)
         AND (@dtTo IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.ExpiryDate IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.ExpiryDate <= @dtTo)
         AND ((Admins.PortTypes.ID IN (' + @passTypeId + '))
         AND (Admins.PortCategories.ID IN (' + @passCategoryId + '))
         AND (Admins.PortTransactionTypes.ID IN (' + @passTransId + '))
         AND (Port.Info.PrintLocationID IN (' + @PrintLocationId + ')))

    GROUP BY Admins.PrintLocations.ArabicName, Admins.PrintLocations.EnglishName'

    EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Reports].[LocationSummary]
    @dtFrom VARCHAR(MAX),
    @dtTo VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passTypeId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passCategoryId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passTransId VARCHAR(MAX),
    @printOption VARCHAR(MAX),
    @printLocationId VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Admins.PLocations.ArabicName AS PLocationA, 
           Admins.PLocations.EnglishName AS PLocationE,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.Info.Printed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Printed,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.Info.Printed = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NotPrinted,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Port.PortPrintLog.PortId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Reprinted

    FROM Port.Info INNER JOIN
           Port.PortRequests ON 
           Port.Info.PassRequestId = Port.PortRequests.ID LEFT JOIN
           Port.PortDefinitions ON 
           Port.PortRequests.PassDefinitionID = Port.PortDefinitions.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortCategories ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassCategoryId = Admins.PortCategories.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortTypes ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassTypeId = Admins.PortTypes.ID  INNER JOIN
           Admins.PortTransactionTypes ON 
           Port.PortDefinitions.PassTransactionTypeId = Admins.PortTransactionTypes.ID INNER JOIN
           Admins.PLocations ON 
           Port.Info.PrintLocationID = Admins.PLocations.ID LEFT JOIN
           Port.PortPrintLog ON Port.PortPrintLog.PortId = Port.Info.ID

    WHERE 
         (@dtFrom IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.IssuanceDate IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.IssuanceDate >= @dtFrom)
         AND (@dtTo IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.ExpiryDate IS NOT NULL AND Port.PortRequests.ExpiryDate <= @dtTo)
         AND Admins.PortTypes.ID IN (@passTypeId)
         AND Admins.PortCategories.ID IN (@passCategoryId)
         AND Admins.PortTransactionTypes.ID IN (@passTransId)
         AND Port.Info.PrintLocationID IN (@PrintLocationId)

    GROUP BY Admins.PrintLocations.ArabicName, Admins.PrintLocations.EnglishName
```

casting to int will cause an error while passing 1,2 in parameter. do not cast it.

Comment: This query will not give the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are spaces in your comma separated list:

```
(1,2)
```

is not the same as

```
(1, 2)
```